Echarts SplitLine overlap AxisLine when opacity is set
It may sounds logical, but the splitLine is overlapping my axisLine when I set an opacity in Echarts.
I would like to achieve this design:

The axis and the split lines have an opacity to 0.3. The correct option should be:
xAxis: {
    axisLine: {
       lineStyle: {
         color: 'black',
         opacity: 0.3,
         width: 1,
      }
    },
    splitLine: {
       lineStyle: {
         color: 'black',
         opacity: 0.3,
         width: 1,
         type: 'dashed'
      }
    }
  }

With this config, I got an overlap at the xAxis:

The only work-around I found is to set splitLine colors:
{
  splitLine: {
    lineStyle: {
       color: color: [
          'none', // This one represents the first splitLine (set on the axis)
          'black',
          'black',
          'black',
          'black',
          ... // until Infinity
       ],
       opacity: 0.3,
       width: 1,
       type: 'dashed'
    }
  }
}

Anyone faced this issue before ?

The easiest solution would probably be to just set the axisLine opacity to 1.
That being said there is a somewaht hacky way to achieve what you want by adding another axis of type 'category'. This enables the usage of splitLine.interval. Note, that you need to know the number of splits beforehand to adjust the data of the 'category' axis. Now you only need to set the appropriate visibilities for axisLines, splitLines and axisLabels.
Example:
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    axisLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        opacity: 0.3,
        width: 2
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      axisLine: { show: true },
      splitLine: {
        show: false
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      axisLine: { show: false },
      axisLabel: { show: false },
      splitLine: {
        show: true,
        interval: (index, value) => {if(index > 0) return true},
        lineStyle: {
          color: 'black',
          opacity: 0.3,
          width: 2,
          type: 'dashed'
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
  ]
};


